# Swift & SpriteKit - switch statement using break

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, switch-statement, break

I have a switch statement that that determines which node name was touched. I have two nodes that overlap. If the top one is touched, I want only the code for the top node case to be executed. So I put a break after that case. Even so, the code for both cases is executed. What is the best way to only trigger the top case? Below is the code:

```
for node in nodeTouched {
   if let currentNode = node.name {
      switch currentNode {
         case "thisIsTheTopNode":
            print("top")
            break
         case "thisIsTheNodeUnderneath":
            print("bottom")
            break
         default:
            break
      }
   }
}
```

Output :

top

bottom

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with above code. Your break statement should work.  Mostly your nodeTouched has both nodes. If yes, then you need to break from for-loop as well.

Comment: in swift, you do not need break

Comment: I bet you that nodeTouched is touching both nodes, and you do not know it, place a print right after your for that says `print("\(nodeTouched.count)")`

Comment: @adev - you were right. I needed to break out of the for loop as well. Duh. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your issue is that you are not breaking from for-loop. You have both nodes present while entering for-loop. This will cause it to iterate over both nodes and it will print both as shown in question. You should `break` the for-loop in this case.